# How to solve a system of nonlinear equations where there are more equations than variables?

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations

I have a system of equations, which is given by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1^2 \\
a_1a_2 \\
a_1a_3 \\
a_2a_1 \\
a_2^2 \\
a_2a_3 \\
a_3a_1 \\
a_3a_2 \\
a_3^2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
k_1 \\
k_2 \\
k_3 \\
k_4 \\
k_5 \\
k_6 \\
k_7 \\
k_8 \\
k_9
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are unknowns and $k_i ,i=1,2,...9$ are knowns. How can I obtain $a_j, j=1,2,3$? The problem I am facing is, if I only consider $a_1^2,a_2^2,a_3^2$, then the corresponding $k_1,k_5,k_9$ might be negative leading to complex values and hence that is not acceptable. 
I need to be evaluate this (i.e find $a_j, j=1,2,3$) at every time instant in my simulation. 
 Any workarounds? Thanks for your time and consideration!

Comment: If $k_i$'s are allowed to be negative you have to allow $a_i$'s to be complex numbers. No 'workaround'.

Comment: Hi! The thing is, $k_i$ are coming as a result of solving a set of differential equation at every time instant in my simulation. Once I get $k_i$, I need to find individual $a_j$.

Comment: Are the possible negatives values "frankly" negative or are they relatively close to $0$ ?

Comment: @nicomezi, actually, the $k_i$ values can be anything as they are given by solution of a differential equation.

Comment: Well, if the way you compute $k_i$ can lead to negatives values, then something is wrong with your model.